Get 2 Input for date picker in ASP.NET
I have this code for get date picker range
<div class="col-md-8">
    <label class="m-t-20">Date Range Pick</label>
    <input class="form-control input-daterange-datepicker" 
           type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015">
</div>

And I have 2 properties in my models.
How can I get both of 2 inputs? I need both of them.
public DateTime ChefFoodPriceFromDate { get; set; }
public DateTime ChefFoodPriceToDate { get; set; }


So you have a javascript date range picker that formats the chosen range in this form 01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015? Or what?

@BenderBoy I use from a java script code for showing the date picker form, But I need to get 2 properties on my view form on c# code

Can you show what the HTTP request looks like?

@BenderBoy can you explain more? I want to get start date and end date from view and pass it to my method

1st question, which one datepicker are you using?

@Maryam12forex when you select a date range and hit send in your browser, you can see what the browser sends to the server in the browser’s dev tools. For example, in Firefox this message looks like the following: https://imgur.com/TG7009o

@ISR I have jquery and bootstarp both of them in my project

@Maryam12forex try to configure you view using this page https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker instead of inputs use your model inputs data using asp-for helpers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-8.0
for example


Since I don't know which datepicker you have used inside your application, I just provide a simple example to let you know how we could get the date and pass it to backend.
We could use js to get the from date and to date and then set the value to two input hidden which could store the two value and it will pass it to the backend by using form post.
More details, you could refer to below example:
I don't use any datepicker, since I don't know which datepicker you have used, but the way is same, you could write the js codes to read the from and to date value and set it to two input hidden field(ChefFoodPriceFromDate and ChefFoodPriceToDate).
<form id="dateRangeForm" method="post" asp-action="PostCalcul">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <label class="m-t-20">Date Range Pick</label>
        <input class="form-control input-daterange-datepicker" id="daterange"
               type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015">
        <!-- Hidden input fields for selected dates -->
        <input type="hidden" id="chefFoodPriceFromDate" name="ChefFoodPriceFromDate">
        <input type="hidden" id="chefFoodPriceToDate" name="ChefFoodPriceToDate">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


@section Scripts{
 
    <script>
    


        $("#dateRangeForm").submit(function (event) {
            // Get the value of the input field
            var dateRange = $("#daterange").val();
            console.log(dateRange);
            // Split the value into two dates
            var dates = dateRange.split(" - ");
            // Assign the values to the hidden input fields
            $("#chefFoodPriceFromDate").val(dates[0]);
            console.log(dates[0]);
            $("#chefFoodPriceToDate").val(dates[1]);
            console.log(dates[1]);
        });

    </script>
}

Result:

